# Creating a SQL Snippet in SQL Operations Studio for MacOS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am starting to use Microsoft's SQL Ops for Mac connection to sql2016 on a Win2016 Server, and it is a nice tool.
In trying to create custom snippets I am running into a problem: following the instructions from MS at [Creating SQL code snippets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-operations-studio/code-snippets?view=sql-server-2017#creating-sql-code-snippets) it just does nothing.

Using this little snippet:

```
"SELECT FROM" : {
    "prefix": "sqlssf",
    "body": "SELECT * FROM $0",
"description": "SELECT FROM"
},
```

saved into sql.json (as per above link) gives json errors.
Pasting in the sample snippet from the page mentioned gives more of the same errors.

I have not tried on a windows machine.

Has anyone had any success with this, or is no one else using this on a mac?

EDIT: Added a missing double quote in the pasted code above.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message suggests, the json file you are trying to save is not a valid one. To fix that, you have to terminate the description fields with double quotes and remove the comma from the end. The end result will look something that:

```
{
    "SELECT FROM" : {
        "prefix": "sqlssf",
        "body": "SELECT * FROM $0",
    "description": "SELECT FROM"
    }
}
```

which worked perfectly for me.